# Proving EVT with epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

Just wondering whether we can prove Extreme Value Theorem purely using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity? Can you show me that proof, if possible? Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean you want a rigorous proof? It's easier to use the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition to prove the sequential characterization of continuity and then use that to prove this theorem.

Comment: Since the theorem deals with continuous functions, one must use some characterization of continuity in the proof. It can be either $\epsilon, \delta$ or some other version like sequential continuity. But more importantly the theorem is a consequence of completeness of real numbers and that part is more important here than the $\epsilon, \delta$.

Comment: As to the proof you may have a look at many proofs given in this [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-boundedness-property.html).

Comment: @DavidReed: Yep that's what I meant. Hmm can you show me where can I get it? I believe someone has proved it somewhere right? I just want to know how it goes and use it to prove my theorem. :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A lemma to this theorem is that a function continuous on a closed, bounded interval is bounded on this interval. Assuming that you have proved this lemma:

Let $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}\ ,\ S = \{\,f(x) \ | \ x \in [a,b]\} $ and $ M := \sup S$

We need to find an $x_M \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_M) = M$

It is a theorem that one can always choose a sequence of points in a set that converges to that set's supremum.

Thus we can choose $y_n \in S$ such that $y_n \to M$. By definition of $S$, $y_n = f(x_n)$ for some $x_n \in [a,b].$ Since $ a \leq x_n \leq b$ for all $n$, $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. By the Bolzano-Weirstrauss Theorem, $\{x_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$, Say $x_{n_k} \to x_M$. By the comparison theorem for sequences, $x_M \in [a,b]$.

Finally, using the sequential characterization of continuity, $$x_{n_k} \to x_M \implies f(x_{n_k}) \to f(x_M)$$

However, $f(x_{n_k}) = y_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $y_n$ and hence must converge to the same limit as $y_n.$

Thus we also have $f(x_{n_k}) \to M$.

By uniqueness of limits we must then have $f(x_M) = M$ and we're done. The case for infimums is virtually identical.